# Можно ли в Python создать экземпляр класса имея только его переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим есть переменная типа `str`

```
a = 'test'
```

можно ли допустим создать экземпляр класса при помощи значения "тест"
Что я имею ввиду:

```
'test'.название_класса
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно используя `__class__`.

```
class A():
    pass

obj = A()
new_obj = obj.__class__()
```